# How exactly do we use queue in Laravel 5.0?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

I'm a new Laravel developer. I tried to use queues but don't know where to start. I did not find any matches after a google search on this.

This is how I tried to use a queue on my controller:

```
   $date = Carbon::now()->addMinute(1);
    Queue::later($date, function(){
                CategoryTags::create([
                   'name' =>  Helper::nowTimestamp()
                ]);
            });
```

The function inside `Queue` gets executed and gives an error like `Queue` does not exist.

I want to call a queue hourly, what am I doing wrong here? How do I implement this?

Comment: Have you had a good look at the docs? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues

Comment: yes and i have no idea how i start use queue for do something hourly , also i use laravel 5

Comment: I answered a question on queued events a while back, maybe it can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331129/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-up-queues-for-laravel-events/30334562#30334562

Comment: as i see , i must run php artisan queue:listen to queue work , how run this code in my host ? i have a directadmin host

Comment: Perhaps SSH? Does this help? http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=10 - once connected you would need to cd into the directory where you laravel project is then run the command.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to define namespace.

```
use Queue;
```

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;

Comment: if i dont use "use" ! program will show error , i use that in my controller => use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;